# IIS 7 URL Rewrite Rule Not Firing

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have created a rewrite rule for javascript and css versioning in IIS 7. The rule is defined as follows:

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
     <rule name="Js/Css Cache Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="(.+/public/(javascript|css)/(Debug|Release)/.+\.)\d+\.(js|css)" />
       <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}{R:4}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
     </rule>
   </rules>
 </rewrite>
```

When I manually test the url against the regex it matches. The url follows this pattern:
http://mytestsite.com/public/javascript/Release/SomeDir/jsfile.20100915140743.js

Any ideas on what I could be missing for the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incoming url ended up being "public/..." because of the level in IIS where it was configured. If I configured at a higher level then it had the full url. I changed my regex to the following: (.*public/(javascript|css)/(Debug|Release)/.+.)\d+.(js|css) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex starts out with `(.+/public/`, which translates to "one or more characters, followed by `/public/`". Your URL as passed to you by IIS starts out with either `/public/` or `public/`, neither of which match your regex. You probably need somthing like `((^|.*/)public/` instead.

Comment: If the URL passed in is either /public/... or public/... wouldn't this be simpler? i.e. (^|/)public/

Comment: nickyt: Yes, it would be simpler, but the URL could also be "/blah/blah/blah/public/..."

Comment: Yeah you're close to what the problem was. The incoming url ended up being "public/..." because of the level in IIS where it was configured. If I configured at a higher level then it had the full url. I changed my regex to the following: (.*public/(javascript|css)/(Debug|Release)/.+\.)\d+\.(js|css)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="permalink">
                    <match url="article/(\D+)(\/)*$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://mywebsite.com/article.aspx?id={R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You should post more answers like this, instead of your spam answers.